# Alternative proofs to integral test that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha^{j^p}$ converges; $0<\alpha,p<1.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

I can prove that $\large{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha^{\left(j^p\right)}\right)}$ converges, where $0<\alpha<1,\ $ and $\ 0<p<1,\ $ by proving that
$$\large{\displaystyle\int_{x=1}^{\infty}\ \alpha^{\left(x^p\right)}} dx$$

converges by using substitution $\ x=u^{\frac{1}{p}},\ $ and then Integration by parts finitely many times. Then by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), the original series must converge as well.

I am looking for alternative proofs to the integral test for the convergence of the original series. Can we use AM-GM, for example? Or some alternative comparison test?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try [the Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm not too familiar with that test, but I just had a go with it. Am I right that the "condensed" series arising from using that test is a geometric series with $r<1,$ and therefore the original series converges? I found this out by comparing the $(n+1)$-th term of the "condensed" series with the $n$-th term of the condensed series, and I think I have shown that the condensed series is geometric with $r<1.$

Comment: I don't get a geometric series, but one that's dominated by a geometric series...

Comment: Yes that's what I meant- I was using language loosely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cauchy Condensation Test is a very powerful thing:

> > Assuming that $a_n\ge a_{n+1}\ge0$ we have $\sum a_n<\infty$ if and only if $\sum 2^na_{2^n}<\infty$.

It's actually easy to prove, or you can  look it up. Apply it to $\sum n^{-p}$ and see what happens.

Here it's sufficient to show that $$\sum 2^n\alpha^{(2^n)^p}<\infty.$$Choose $k>0$ so $$\alpha^k<\frac12$$and then choose $N$ so $$2^{np}>kn\quad(n\ge N).$$Now $$\sum_{n\ge N}2^n\alpha^{2^{np}}\le\sum_{n\ge N}2^n\alpha^{kn}=\sum(2\alpha^k)^n<\infty.$$

Comment: I find it easier to digest by trying to show that: The $n+1$-th term divided by the $n$-th term is eventually less than some $0<\beta<1,\ $ which is probably basically what you've done.