# Convergence of a series of $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}r^{j^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $0<r<1$ and $0<s<1$, how can we tell whether the following series converges?
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}r^{j^{s}}.
$$
I am not sure which convergence test we can use in this case. I did some graphings and it seems that the series will converge. Thank you in advanced for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative proofs to integral test that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha^{j^p}$ converges; $0&lt;\alpha,p&lt;1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190377/alternative-proofs-to-integral-test-that-lim-n-to-infty-sum-j-1n-alpha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r=e^{-a}$, where $a\in(0,\infty)$ (since $0<r<1$). By the integral, test, the convergence of the series is equivalent to the finiteness of the following integral,
$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^s}\,dx.$$
Let $x\mapsto x^{1/s}$ so that your integral becomes
$$I(s)=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty x^{1/s-1} e^{-ax}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(1+1/s)}{a^{1/s}},$$
which is finite for any $s\in(0,1)$. This will also give you the asymptotic behavior of your sum as $s\to 0^+$, using Stirling's formula:
$$I(s)\sim \sqrt{2\pi/s}\,e^{1/s\log(1/s)}e^{-1/s}a^{-1/s}.$$